# How can I get the value stored in that array 'my_array' Cypress?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, each, cypress

```
cy.get(tableBody)
    .each(($el, $index) => {
        let myArray = []
        let mydata = $el.text()
        if($index!==1) {
            myArray.push(mydata.trim())
        }
    }).then((my_list) => {
        cy.log(my_list)
```

Here, my_list print the value same as what cy.get(tableBody) return. It's like cy.get(tableBody).then((my_list) => { cy.log(my_list) }. I want that array and use that later. I know I can get return like this

```
TableDataBeforeSorting() {
    let myArray = []
    cy.get(tableBody).each(($el, $index) => {
        let mydata = $el.text()
        if($index!==1) {
            myArray.push(mydata.trim())
        }    
    })
    return myArray
```

But I want it using then so that I can use it later. Any suggestion or feedback will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that when Cypress doesn't do what I want in terms of saving data to variables to use later, I can save data to disk:

```
// save it
cy.XYZcommand().then((results) => {
  cy.writeFile('temp.txt', results)
})

...

cy.readFile('temp.txt')
  .then((results) => {
  // do something with it
})

...
// clean it up
cy.exec('rm temp.txt')
```